# About the notation of XOR-SAT

Tags: np-complete, optimization, np-hard, np

I am a bit confused by the notation here, http://www.boazbarak.org/sos/files/lec3.pdf

- Given 3 Boolean variables $x_i, x_j, x_k$ what is supposed to be the meaning of $x_i \oplus x_j \oplus x_k$?

  Is this to be understood as say $((x_i \oplus x_j )\oplus x_k )$? And hence this is true for only $2$ cases $x_i =0, x_j = 1, x_k =0$ and $x_i = 1, x_j = 0, x_k = 0$ ?

  But then we could have bracketed it as $(x_i \oplus (x_j \oplus x_k))$ and then the only true assignments would have looked as $x_i = 0, x_j =1, x_k = 0$ and $x_i = 0, x_j =0, x_k = 1$ and these are different.

  Also one could have used commutativity to write it in other re-arranged forms and gotten different true selections!
- But then the note above seems to claim that if the $x_a$s are coming as coordinates of a vector $x \in \{\pm 1\}^n$ then the product $x_ix_j x_k$ is the same as having a linear equation in those $3$ variables. Why so? (for example an assignment $x_i = x_j = x_k =1$ will evaluate to $1$ for the product but under mod 2 arithmetic $x_i + x_j + x_k = 0$ for this assignment!)

Also it is being claimed that the value of $x_ix_jx_k$ can only be $\pm 1$ (which they denote as $a_{ijk}$) for $x \in \{\pm 1\}^n$ and that is okay only if one ignores the first claim that these are supposed to be linear equations!

---

This $x_ix_j x_k$ product notation looks more confusing later on when they say that corresponding to two subsets $S, T \subset \{1,..,n\}$ one can take two expressions of the form $x_S = \prod_{i \in S} x_i$ and $x_T = \prod_{i \in T} x_i$ and construct $x_U = x_S x_T$ and that this somehow corresponds to doing ``$U = S \oplus T$" - and I don't know what it means to take a XOR of two subsets!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XOR is an associative operation, so $x_i \oplus x_j \oplus x_k$ is unambiguous. There are in fact four satisfying assignments, given by
$$ (x_i,x_j,x_k) \in \{(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,1)\}. $$

XOR satisfies the useful property
$$ (-1)^{x \oplus y} = (-1)^x (-1)^y. $$
Therefore $x_i \oplus x_j \oplus x_k = 1$ is the same as
$$ (-1)^{x_i} (-1)^{x_j} (-1)^{x_k} = (-1)^1.$$
If we think of our variables as $X_i = (-1)^{x_i}$, then the equation $x_i \oplus x_j \oplus x_k = 1$ is completely equivalent to $X_i X_j X_k = -1$. Since XOR is really just addition in the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$, you can think of both formulations as linear equations.

---

Yet another interpretation of XOR is in terms of sets. Just as AND corresponds to intersection and OR to union, the XOR operation corresponds to *symmetric difference*, sometimes denoted $\triangle$ or $\Delta$. You can easily check that $x_S x_T = x_{S \triangle T}$, essentially using $x_i^2 = 1$.

Comment: (1) If $x_i$ are the Boolean variables then a ``linear" equation in them has to look like $a_ix_i + a_jx_j + a_kx_k$ for $a_i, a_j a_k  \in \{\pm\}^n$. But neither does $x_i \oplus x_j \oplus x_k$ nor does $X_i X_j X_k$ seem to be linear equations. Even over mod-2 operations the expression say $x_i + x_j + x_k$ is *not* the same as $x_ix_jx_k$. I am not getting your point! (2) Are you saying that when $\oplus$ is used between two sets we should read that as symmetric difference? So this is a new notation!

Comment: (1) If you think of the $x_i$ as elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, then $x_i \oplus x_j \oplus x_k = 1$ is just a linear equation (read $+$ for $\oplus$). (2) It's somewhat uncommon to use $\oplus$ for set, but the corresponding operation is definitely symmetric difference.

Comment: Okay - I can see why $x_i \oplus x_j \oplus x_k = x_i + x_j + x_k$ over mod 2 operations but the whole proof is set up in terms of the product $x_i x_j x_k$ and that is clearly not the same as either of these two things above!

Comment: It's exactly the same if you replace $x_i$ with $(-1)^{x_i}$.

Comment: Can't I think of it as $x_i \in \{-1,1\}$ and then XOR behaving as $x_i \oplus x_j = -x_ix_j$? Then $x_i \oplus x_j \oplus x_k = x_ix_jx_k$ and this evaluates to $1$ on exactly the $4$ options as before but with $0$ replaced by $-1$? Won't the proof in the link go through in this form too?

Comment: What you're describing is using the XNOR operation instead of the XOR operation. When XNORing an odd number of literals, the result is exactly the same as XORing them.

Comment: There is a problem with your translation. Your $X_i = 1$ if $x_i = 0$ and $X_i = -1$ if $x_i =1$. So your $X_i$ are $\pm 1$ valued. So they also satisfy the constraint $X_i^2 = 1$ . But $X_iX_jX_k = \mp 1$ when $x_i \oplus x_j \oplus x_k = 0,1$. So corresponding to a constraint of the form $x_i \oplus x_k \oplus x_k = a_{ijk}$ your constraint will have to be $a_{ijk}X_iX_jX_k = -1$ and that is a different constraint from what is there in part (b) of Theorem 1 (page 1). Isn't that a problem?

Comment: There is absolutely no problem, since $a_{ijk} \in \{0,1\}$. The XOR is $0/1$-valued.

Comment: Well the disconnect is this, If the instance contained the equation $x_i \oplus x_j \oplus x_k = a_{ijk}$ then the corresponding equation in $X$ space will not be $a_{ijk}X_iX_jX_k =1$ (..as it needs to look like in part (b) of Theorem 1 of the notes..)

Comment: Right, it will be $X_iX_jX_k = (-1)^{a_{ijk}}$. The notes might have a mistake somewhere. Just ignore it.

Comment: Hope nothing goes wrong in the proof! :)

Comment: Also this proof has this other confusing aspect that it is somehow fudging the distinction between what is a "constraint" and what is an "objective" function. I would have thought that the equations $a_{ijk}x_i \otimes x_j \otimes x_k =1$ (lets keep with the typo!) are part of the objective as in the objective is a sum of these terms $a_{ijk}x_i \otimes x_j \otimes x_k $ so that it counts the number of satisfied clauses.

Comment: But then I don't know why it is asking for the pseudo-distribution to be consistent with these clauses which are part of the objective and are not the constraint! I would have thought that the pseudo-distribution only needs to be consistent with the constraints (which here are the equations $X_i^2 =1$)

Comment: No, these equations *are* the constraints.

Comment: Then what is the objective?

Comment: We're trying to maximize the number of satisfied constraints.

Comment: I suggest you contact a local graduate student and continue the discussion locally. This site is not a discussion forum.

Comment: But then that "objective" when written as a function will be equal to $\sum a_{ijk}x_i \oplus x_j \oplus x_k$ - it clicks a $1$ or a $0$ for each satsified or not clause. But in this way of writing the equations are *not* constraints and the only constraints are $x_i^2 =1$.

Comment: You write these constraints as polynomials in the $X_i$. I repeat my suggestion of contacting a local knowledgeable graduate student, postdoc or professor, and won't answer any more questions.